# "launching 'project' has encountered .." , project file does not exist

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, launch

I wanted to write 'hello world' in eclipse c++, but it does not work

[image: table]

I go to Run configurations, what config options for c++ programs should i give?

I know I don't care about 'debug' - only 'release', but how to do that?

[image: u]

Comment: Did the program compile properly?
It seems like you don't have a binary file to run.

Comment: @John, no it did not!

Comment: Could you show your build settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:
File->New->C++ Project
You will get a pop up window. Type the name of the project you want. Then, below it says executable and inside this folder, I have (by default I guess) Empty Project.
Then click Next and Finish.

Now the project appears in the left column of Eclipse. I right click it and select New->File and name it main.cpp

The main window of Eclipse opens the file main.cpp and I write inside:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
std::cout << "Hello Erjan\n" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Then I click on **Build**, it's the hammer icon in the middle of the toolbar. The code compiles and we are ready to launch it!

So, click on Run icon (3 positions right of the Build icon) and you should see the output in the console.

Comment: omg, thx, it works, i was thinking you just hit Run and it must work - so i was wrong assuming, "run" button will do both "build & run"

Comment: So did I, when I first used Eclipse! Happy that I helped. :)

Comment: what if i want to run this same code - main() in file called doggy.cpp? DOES IT HAVE TO be called main.cpp for it to run? does eclipse always look for file called main.cpp?

Comment: Your program **must** have only one function, named main. -the main function of the program-.

Answer (score 1):

The first step, create new project and try proper toolchains.
Second step, Project >> build project.
Third step, right click on new executive file and run or debug it.