# Eclipse C compiler throwing errors

Tags: c, eclipse

I was trying to compile helloworld.c in Eclipse Oxygen.1 on Mac 10.12.6

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

and it throws such an error:

```
20:41:02 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****
make all 
Building target: HelloWorld
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
gcc  -o "HelloWorld"  ./helloworld.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [HelloWorld] Error 1

20:41:03 Build Finished (took 938ms)
```

I am quite sure that the problem isn't the code itself, but what?

Comment: It looks like you might have a stale version of `./helloworld.o` getting in the way.  Try deleting it.

Comment: @TomKarzes tried deleting it, but the problem still comes up.........

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know enough about how you're building it to be of more help.  The `gcc` command shown appears to be picking up an existing `./helloworld.o`, but I don't see where it's creating it from `./helloworld.c`.  Are you sure you're looking in the right directory?

Comment: I wrote the code, ran the eclipse compiler, and it generated a new folder called Debug and threw that error, and I tried deleting the helloworld.o within the Debug folder and retried the compling process and it generates the same set of files and threw the same error.......

Comment: Well, a simple way to test it is to copy it to a new name, e.g. `newworld.c`, then build and run that.  If it behaves differently, then you have a build problem.  If not, then something else is going on.

Comment: I found out the copied document has no code in it, and I found out the solution to the 1st problem is that I should save the code, but now it says "Launching HelloWorld has encountered a problem.  Program File does not exists"......

Comment: I think the problem is that you've created Cross-GCC project, try changing this by going into Project Properties -> C/C++ build -> Tool chain editor and setting something like Linux GCC or Macos GCC as tool chain.

Comment: @VTT just tried now, and it shows the same prompt again.......

Comment: Solved using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221129/launching-project-has-encountered-project-file-does-not-exist. Thanks for all your valuable time in helping me~